# Can't get colored image on Android usin objloader library

Tags: android, eclipse, processing

I have made a sketch in processing using saitoobjloader and controlP5 librarys, and it works just fine, and after that i have exported as an android app to import it in eclipse. I have runned it then on my phone, from eclipse, and it works, except that, everything is black and white.I have tried model.disableMaterial(), model.disableTexture() and it does not work, I have seted for android 2.3.3, 4.2.2, 4.4 and it also don't work...stil black and white. I have tried primitive debug by disabeling everything i can one by one: the animation, the boject loaded, screen orientation and stil black and white. Idon't have any permisions aded, and the only change i have made is for screen orientation in manifes aplication: Debuggable --> null, Screen orientation --> unspecified, Config changes --> orientation.
Below you can see my code from eclipse:

```
package processing.test.my_cnc_obj_with_gui_mooving_animation;

import processing.core.*; 

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import saito.objloader.*; 
import controlP5.*; 



public class My_cnc_obj_with_GUI_mooving_animation extends PApplet {




OBJModel model;
ControlP5 sb;

float rotX;
float rotY;
float zoom = 1;
float translateX;
float translateY;
float k;
int i;
float initlength = 250;
int initlengthX = 150;
int initlengthY = 150;
int initlengthZ = 80;
float moveIndex;
float AXA_X;
float AXA_Y;
float AXA_Z;

public void setup() {
  model = new OBJModel(this, "CNC colorat pentru processing.obj");
  model.scale(400);
  model.translateToCenter();
  //model.disableTexture();
  model.disableMaterial();
  //model.disableDebug();
  controlereGUI();
  noStroke();
}

public void draw() {
  background(50, 34, 32);
  lights();
  // fill(255,0,255);
  pushMatrix();
  translate(width/2 - 50, height/2, 0);
  rotateX(rotY);
  rotateY(rotX);
  model.draw();
  model.disableMaterial();
  popMatrix();
  animation();
}

public void mouseDragged()
{
  rotX += (mouseX - pmouseX) * 0.01f;
  rotY -= (mouseY - pmouseY) * 0.01f;
}

public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

      int orientation = newConfig.orientation;
      model.disableMaterial();
      //Something strange happened... bail out!
      if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED)
        return;
      orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;

      if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        //Landscape config
      }
      if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        //Portrait config
      }
    }

/*public void mouseWheel(MouseEvent e) {
  translateX = translateX-e.getAmount()*(mouseX)/100;
  translateY = translateY-e.getAmount()*(mouseY)/100;
  zoom += e.getAmount() / 100;
  model.scale(zoom);
}*/


public void controlereGUI() {
  sb = new ControlP5(this);

  sb.getTab("default")
    //.activateTab("Assisted_controll")
    //.activateEvent(true)
    .setHeight(40)
      .setLabel("Assisted controll")
        .setId(3)
          ;

  sb.getTab("Manual_controll")
    //.activateTab("Manual_controll")
    //.activateEvent(true)
    .setHeight(40)
      .setLabel("Manual controll")
        .setId(1)
          ;

  sb.addTab("Settings")
    //.activateTab("Settings")
    .setHeight(40)
      .setWidth(60)
        .setLabel("Settings")
          .setId(2)
            .setColorBackground(color(0, 160, 100))
              //.activateEvent(true)
              .setColorLabel(color(255))
                .setColorActive(color(255, 128, 0))
                  ;

  sb.addSlider("AXA_X")
    .setPosition(10, 70)
      //.setWidth(300)
      .setSize(300, 30)
        .setRange(initlength, 0)
          //.setValue(128)
          .setSliderMode(Slider.FLEXIBLE)
            ;

  sb.addSlider("AXA_Y")
    .setPosition(10, 110)
      //.setWidth(300)
      .setSize(300, 30)
        .setRange(initlengthY, -initlengthY)
          //.setValue(128)
          .setSliderMode(Slider.FLEXIBLE)
            .setColorForeground(0xffFC0000)
              .setColorBackground(color(150, 0, 0))
                ;

  sb.addSlider("AXA_Z")
    .setPosition(10, 150)
      //.setWidth(300)
      .setSize(300, 30)
        .setRange(initlengthZ + 120, 70)
          //.setValue(128)
          .setSliderMode(Slider.FLEXIBLE)
            .setColorForeground(0xff0BFC00)
              .setColorBackground(color(100, 150, 0))
                ;

  sb.addButton("Start_movement")
    .setBroadcast(false)
      .setValue(128)
        .setPosition(120, height-160)
          //.setImages(imgs)
          .setSize(90, 50)
            .setCaptionLabel("Start movement")
              .setColorBackground(color(100, 150, 0))
                //.setVisible(false)
                .setBroadcast(true)
                  ;


  sb.addButton("Stop_movement")
    .setValue(128)
      .setPosition(120, height-100)
        //.setImages(imgs)
        .setSize(90, 50)
          .setCaptionLabel("Stop movement")
            .setColorBackground(color(150, 0, 0))
              //.setVisible(false)
              ;
}

public void animation() {

  for (int i = 0; i < model.getVertexCount () - 6090; i++) {
    PVector orgv = model.getVertex(i);
    PVector tmpv = new PVector();
    tmpv.x = orgv.x;
    tmpv.y = orgv.y;
    tmpv.z = orgv.z + (k * AXA_Y);
    model.setVertex(i, tmpv);
  }
  if ((AXA_Y != 0)) {
    if (moveIndex < AXA_Y)
      moveIndex ++;
    else
      if (moveIndex > AXA_Y)
      moveIndex --;
    else
      k = 0;
    k = 1;
  } else {
    moveIndex = AXA_Y;
    k = 0;
  }
}


  public int sketchWidth() { return 800; }
  public int sketchHeight() { return 700; }
  public String sketchRenderer() { return P3D; }
}
```

I don'tknow why is stil black and white.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
It seems that i must use a combination of use of material (not disable it) and after drawing the model to stop the lights. So, it should be like in the code above, with this modifications:

```
  public void setup() {
  model = new OBJModel(this, "CNC colorat pentru processing.obj");
  model.scale(400);
  model.translateToCenter();
  controlereGUI();
  noStroke();
}

  public void draw() {
  background(50, 34, 32);
  lights();
  // fill(255,0,255);
  pushMatrix();
  translate(width/2 - 50, height/2, 0);
  rotateX(rotY);
  rotateY(rotX);
  model.draw();
  popMatrix();
  noLights();
  animation();
}
```

However, it seems that the 3D model remains still black and white even if is coloured. The 3D model was modified with Blender v2.71 (imported as .wrl file and exported as .obj with .mtl file). The .wrl file has been initial colored and when it was imported in Blender everything was ok, the model was colored. It seems that processing can't get the material. The debug shows: Material 'Shape.1687' not defined, ..., Material 'Shape.001' not defined, 
Material 'Shape' not defined
I don't know where the problem is: inside saitoobjloader or the .obj and .mtl files....

Answer (score 0):

Solved the second problem too. The problem is in file's name "CNC colorat pentru processing".
It seems that saito's objloader parser does not read spaces caracter (" ") in files name, so when i am making a new obj file (in blender or any other), i should have save it with the name "CNC_colorat_pentru_processing", or any other name that does not contain space caracter.